# launch android app in context of my application

Tags: java, android, sandbox, android-context, android-security

I want to launch an app in context of my application (for sandboxing purposes).

I read that for application launching, android uses `bindApplication` and `performLaunch` methods that are hidden from programmers. After that, I implemented these methods with java reflection, but it doesn't work.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I launch an app in android without `startActivity` and Intent?
2. Could I copy the context of another app into my app?

Comment: You might consider posting some minimal code that reproduces the problem you are having for starters.

Answer (score 1):

In Android each app runs in its own process (unless until you have multiple processes in your app), so if try to launch another app from your app, that app will run in its own process.

Your first question:

Activities are entering point to access UI of an app, so if you want to launch some UI you have to call startActivity(), also Intent is required even if you are launching a service or activity.

Second question :

Since an app runs in its own process its not possible to use context of another app.

Ankit